# Set weight for configurable product

Tags: magento-1.8

Is it possible at some point to have problems if I set attribute weight to be visible for Configurable products as well? I want to set the weight for a configurable product in order to display it on product listing and I don't want to add a new attribute. I am asking to be sure that shipping rate will not be influenced by this setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify weight for each on simple products which is a part of configurable product. So make sure that those two values match and you should be fine.

Comment: so..if it is the same weight for configurable as for simple products associated, everything should be fine. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can specify the weight for each simple product to account for the weight difference. E.g. size 6 and size 12 shoes of the same model can be different in weight. And in large quantities this can have significant impact on shipping price.